# Weak Convergence of Average of Dirac-delta to Lebesgue-measure on Unit Interval

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

So I am kind of stuck here:

I need to show that $\delta_n \overset{w}{\rightarrow}\lambda$, where $\delta_n := \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{\frac{i}{n}}\left( (a,b) \right)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac symbol and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\left( \left[0,1\right], \vert \quad \vert\right)$.

I want to use Portmanteau to show that:

for $(a,b) \subset \left[ 0,1 \right]$, it holds that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{\frac{i}{n}}\left( (a,b) \right) \geq \lambda\left( (a,b) \right)$.

Intuitively it should work, as it seems to approximate the Riemann Sum of a function $f\in \mathcal{C}_b\left( [0,1] \right)$, but I have a hard time formalizing the proof.

Any hint/help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: First you need to get the problem straight. Your $\delta_n$ is not a measure, it is a _number_...

Comment: And not to mention that the current definition overrides the meaning of $\delta_{\bullet}$. Anyway, if you want to utilize Portmanteau, it seems more natural to me to test the convergence against bounded continuous functions, i.e., $$ \forall f\in C_b([0,1])\:\quad \int_{[0,1]} f(x) \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_{i/n}(dx)\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\int_{[0,1]} f(x)\,dx. $$ Is there any reason to test this against open intervals instead?

Comment: @SangchulLee Correct me if I am wrong, but there is no difference, as I would have to calculate the measure of the preimage anyway and it would be an open set

Comment: Of course Portnamteau theorem guarantees that either options will work, but using continuous functions has certain advantage in that you can directly compute the limit of the integral $$\int_{[0,1]} f(x) \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_{i/n}(dx)\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\int_{[0,1]}f(x)\,dx$$ when $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @SangchulLee To get it right: you are using that the Lebesgue-integral of a cont. and bounded function on the reals is the Riemann-integral, hence the Riemann Sum with $x_{i} - x_{i-1} = 1/n$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: @SangchulLee Okay, thank you! I think thats enough for me to write it down, feeling kind of dumb now.